# Exclude macOS hidden files from AWS S3 sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, amazon-s3, synchronization, aws-cli

I'm syncing the entire contents of an external hard drive, used with macOS, to an S3 bucket. I'd like to exclude all macOS hidden files.

I've tried:

```
aws s3 sync --dryrun --exclude "^\." --exclude "\/\." ./ s3://bucketname
```

However, the result when I run that is exactly the same as just:

```
aws s3 sync --dryrun . s3://bucketname
```

So, I must be doing something wrong.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: No success here either, but it seemed to work to add several excludes individually `... --exclude "*.DS_Store" --exclude ".git*"`

Answer (score 6):

`aws s3 sync --dryrun . s3://bucketname --exclude ".*" --exclude "*/.*"`

Adding two exclusion arguments will hide both the specified files in the current directory as well as any in subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
aws s3 sync --dryrun . s3://bucketname --exclude ".*"
```

However, I don't think it will exclude such files in sub-directories.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
aws s3 sync --dryrun --exclude '*/.*'
```

This *should* remove any hidden files, including in subfolders.

Comment: Just tried it, it didn't.

Comment: This won't remove hidden files in the root folder, but removes all other ones. See my answer for details. Try --exclude '*._*' (macOS only).

Answer (score 0):

```
aws s3 sync /local/dir/ s3://bucket/dir --exclude '*/.*' --dryrun
```

or, if you're just syncing a dir without any sub dirs:

```
aws s3 sync /local/dir/ s3://bucket/dir --exclude '*._*' --dryrun
```

(EDIT) Somehow didn't see the answer from @Tim. Use that. Lol.

After trying to figure this out myself, I found out that the regex used in the --exclude flag has to do with the entire directory's name, so if you have two files and want to exclude the hidden one, for example:

```
/my/dir/._video.mp4
/my/dir/video.mp4
```

you need to make a regular expression that takes into account the whole directory, including the forward slashes (/). Luckily, since hidden files usually start with a ".", we can deduce that right before that should be a "/", unless you're trying to exclude files in the root dir, of course. If you do need to exclude hidden files in the root of the dir you're syncing, than instead you could use:

```
--exclude '*._*'
```

FYI, the above will exclude every file with a "._" anywhere in the name, but if you're naming files like that intentionally, may I offer a piece of advice: *stop doing that.* In my experience, macOS starts its hidden file names with a dot (.) followed by an underscore (_), which we can use to our advantage. Even so, *I* still probably prefer to use:

```
--exclude '*/.*'
```

mainly because if a few hidden files from the root of my syncing directory get uploaded, that's fine with me. I just want the vast majority of the hidden files (i.e., all other hidden files) to be excluded, since I have many subdirectories with many hidden files.

I use `'*/.*'` just in case I have files named with "._" in there, which against my own advice, happens from time to time. In my defense, it's usually because certain characters get automatically converted to an underscore when a file is downloaded from online or something. Rant over.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

aws s3 sync --recursive --dryrun --exclude '*/.*'

Comment: there is no `--recursive` for sync